# Como puedo incorporar la categoria de html para crear un proyecto nuevo?

Tags: html, netbeans

Estoy comenzando en este ámbito. 
Inicié netbeans y cuando quise crear el proyecto me da la opción de Java, Java Fx, Maven, Netbeans Moludes y Samples. 
Guiandome por videotutoriales no pude encontrar la solución a mi problema. 
Esto le sucedió a alguien?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Supongo que tienes apache netbeans verdad?

Answer (score 2):

Bueno primeramente debes asegurarte de haber descargado el instalador correcto:

Dirigete a la pagina de [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.0.2/) y veras lo siguiente:

[image: NetBeans]

Si te fijas no todos tienen la opción para **HTML**, según esto podrias descargar el que se adecue a tus desarrollos, [para más información](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html#createproject).

Me parece que tambien podrias probar dirigiendote al nenú herramientas/plugins y veras lo siguiente:

[image: net]

Posiblemente tambien puedas añadirlo alli.

Puedes revisar también [éste enlace](https://www.zeppelinux.es/como-anadir-el-plugin-php-en-netbeans-ide/) posiblemente la información que se encuentra allí te ayude a guiarte mejor, el ejemplo está con **PHP** pero con **HTML** deberia ser lo mismo.

Espero te sirva esta información ;) Saludos

Comment: Como complemento a tu respuesta, ¿se puede añadir algún plugin para agregar la funcionalidad al Netbeans que tiene quien pregunta?

Comment: Bueno, abriendo el menú herramientas y luego plugins. Podremos encontrar los instalados y me parece que desde allí es posible

Comment: Israel, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Intenté por donde me indicaste pero en la pantalla ya está instalado. Que otra opción me queda?

Comment: Con que versión de NetBeans estas trabajando??

Comment: Ahh y una pregunta más el plugin se encuentra activado??

Comment: Israel, la versión es Netbeans Ide 8.2 64 bts.